# Probability of having a match

Tags: probability

For a standard match problem with 'n' hats,

[$n \to \infty$]

The Probability that none of the hats have a match is $e^{-1}$

The probability that at least one of the hats have a match is $1-e^{-1}$

The Probability that all the $n$ hats have their match is $\frac{1}{n!}$,this was my actual question,

**P(all the hats have match) = $\frac{1}{n!}$ = $1 -$ P(None of the hats get matched) = $1 - e^{-1}$**

This is same as **P( Atleast one of the hats have a match )** I am confused, where am I wrong , can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: The probability that all $n$ hats match is $1/n!\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty$

Comment: In any case, it couldn't be $\mathrm e$, since $\mathrm e\gt1$.

Comment: If you perform the experiment with $0,1,2,\ldots$ people, then the expected number of experiments in which all hats match is $\mathrm e$ :-)

Comment: @joriki, Thank you!

Comment: @joriki How do we perform an infinite number of experiments ;)

Comment: **P(All the hats match)** is not **1 - P(None of the hats match)**, due to the third option that only some of the hats match.